# What is the significance of "product" in formulas? How are formulas made?

Tags: homework-and-exercises

I know it's a weird question but can anyone help me understand this. In the formula, F=m.a, why are we multiplying m into a. In math when we multiply a x b, we mean sum of a, m times.

```
5x4=20
4+4+4+4+4=20
5+5+5+5=20
```

I understand that F is directly proportional to m and F is also directly proportional to a as well. Therefore as m and a increases F also increases, but the formula could also be F=m+a, in this case also F increases as m and a increases.
Like if we redefine every formulas in terms of addition instead of product then what difference would it make? and if i see a phenomena that increases with respect to a as well as b then why should I multiply them together?

Comment: You are apparently trying to turn physics into a math problem.  Note that physics is NOT math.

Comment: This is also not what is meant by multiplication in math

Comment: @GrapefruitIsAwesome If you know it, then please explain. That's what I'm trying to understand. Physics uses math to solve problems. So there must be some logical reasoning and rules that connects both of them. I think the answer lies in the history of math and physics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deep answer is the group structure of the physical theory. A mathematical group is a set of objects that can be pairwise combined ("multiplied") so the result is another object in the group, there is an invariant object that leaves other objects unchanged (often called "1"), and inverses, so that $a \times a^{-1}=1$. Normal multiplication (the objects can be real numbers or rational numbers) is an obvious example, but many other things can obey group structures. Adding numbers is another group structure where the invariant object is zero and the inverses negative numbers, rotations make up other groups, and so on... The point is that this is much more fundamental than multiplication seen as repeated addition (which only works for positive integers).

We know from observation how objects move under the influence of different forces and masses, and can make a mathematical model of it. Double the force, and the acceleration doubles. The proportionality of acceleration to force by definition means $a = k F$ for some constant $k$. Similarly we see that there should be a mass term, and by setting the units of mass and force right we can make $k=1$ and get a simple formula. This formula obeys the group structure of real number multiplication: I can get the same acceleration by doubling the force and mass simultaneously, there is some mass (1 kg) that makes any force accelerate exactly by the same number as we denote the force, and so on.

This is a simple case, and there are other kinds of "multiplication" that work differently (scalar products, cross products), but they all have their own well-defined algebraic structures. We observe what objects do, then make a mathematical theory that predicts it well, and usually it will have a group or other algebraic structure. Indeed, much of modern physics is built on manipulating such structures since their properties give rise to important physical insights such as symmetries and conservation laws.

Answer (score 1):

If you set $F=m+a$ ,  $F$ will not be proportional to $a$, if you double $a$ ,  $F$ will not double.

So if you have $F$  proportional to  $a$ and $F$ proportional $m$ , you have $F=k×m×a$.  After defining $m$ and $a$, one  define the unit of $F$ so that $k=1$.